# Design patterns used in Spock

Tags: design-patterns, spock

Question:  What are a couple design pattern examples used in the Spock framework?

I am going to be doing a presentation on the Spock framework and after looking at their main site I'm realizing that there isn't a lot of information about Spock out on the web.  One of the aspects I should talk about is a design pattern or two and so I'm wondering what a couple of examples might be.

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do the homework yourself?

Comment: Of course, and I always have.  However, after choosing to do Spock as my presentation, I'm realizing that there is little to no information out on the web about it, much less design patterns.

Comment: There is a fair amount of information on the web, though maybe not the one you are looking for. It's not common to document design patterns used internally in the code. The best way to find them is to browse the codebase.

Comment: Or are you looking for design patterns in the public API? That might be a bit harder than usual because 1. Spock's public API is (intentionally) quite small, especially if you don't count the DSL part 2. when using an expressive language like Groovy, fewer design patterns are needed than when using, say, Java. I'm sure you can find something though. For example in the extension SPI, which will (officially) go public in 1.0. Last Gr8Conf even had a talk on it, and the slides are available. Also, all extensions in the Spock codebase (`IgnoreExtension`, `SpringExtension`, etc.) make use of it.

Comment: Were you wondering how Spock is designed, or are you wondering more about what different design patterns Spock is used for testing?